# Android nougat play store not displaying existing app in search list

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have published app in play store, app is displaying in search list below android nougat. But while searching with android os version nougat app is not showing in search list.

Any information will help full.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic Beyond that, it is unclear what "android O(nougat)" means, since "O" and "nougat" are not the same thing. But, in general, questions about app distribution channels are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `android o != nougat`

Comment: my bad. android 7 nougat. not O.